# Delete from GridView bound to objects calling method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using a GridView bound to a list of objects rather than a direct SQL query. The population of this if working and so are the updates. I have manually generated the insert for this gridview and this is working as well. 
When trying to run the delete command from the gridview, the correct method is being called however none of the parameters are being populated. The only required parameter for this is @ID however, reading other posts, the general fix has been to add all parameters, but still to no avail.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewBands" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="BandsDataSource" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="1375px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AgencyID" SortExpression="AgencyID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("AgencyID") %>' ReadOnly ="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="there is an error?" Text="*`"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add New Line" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newAgencyID" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AgencyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TypeID" SortExpression="TypeID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("TypeID") %>' ReadOnly ="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newTypeID" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("TypeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CompanyID" SortExpression="CompanyID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newCompanyID" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office" SortExpression="Office">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Office") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newOffice" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Office") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SequenceID" SortExpression="SequenceID" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("SequenceID") %>' ReadOnly ="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newSequenceID" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SequenceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minimmum" SortExpression="Minimmum">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Minimmum") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newMinimum" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Minimmum") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Capped" SortExpression="Capped">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Capped") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newCapped" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Capped") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fixed" SortExpression="fixed">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("fixed") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newFixed" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fixed") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flat" SortExpression="Flat">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Flat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newFlat" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Flat") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SequenceLimit" SortExpression="SequenceLimit">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("SequenceLimit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newSequenceLimit" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SequenceLimit") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Rate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newRate" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ActiveFrom" SortExpression="ActiveFrom">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtActiveFrom" runat="server" Width="200px" Text='<%# Bind("ActiveFrom") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newActiveFrom" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActiveFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActiveFrom") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ActiveTo" SortExpression="ActiveTo">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtActiveTo" runat="server" Width="200px" Text='<%# Bind("ActiveTo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="newActiveTo" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActiveTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActiveTo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />

        </asp:GridView>
```

The data source is as below, with the other working methods. It is just the delete method that isn't populating any of the parameters.

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="BandsDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="SelectBands" TypeName="App_Code.Billing+BillingBand" UpdateMethod="UpdateBands" DeleteMethod="RemoveBand" InsertMethod="AddNewBand">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name ="AgencyID" Type ="Int64" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="AgencyID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TypeID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Office" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Minimmum" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Capped" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="fixed" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Flat" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceLimit" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Rate" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveFrom" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveTo" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Object" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="AgencyID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TypeID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Office" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Minimmum" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Capped" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="fixed" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Flat" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceLimit" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Rate" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveFrom" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveTo" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Object" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="AgencyID" Type="Object"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="TypeID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Office" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Minimmum" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Capped" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="fixed" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Flat" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceLimit" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Rate" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveFrom" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveTo" Type="Object" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Object" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have tried to manually populate the parameters being using similar to the below, however I have not been able to find a way to populate the parameter based on the 'selected' line for deletion.

```
Protected Sub BandsDataSource_Deleting(sender As Object, e As ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs) Handles BandsDataSource.Deleting
    e.InputParameters("ID") = GridViewBands.SelectedRow.ID.ToString()
End Sub
```

But this is returning a NULL reference exception.

This is the delete method for example, the update and add methods are in the same format and are working correctly.

```
        Public Sub RemoveBand(AgencyID, TypeID, CompanyID, Office, SequenceID, Minimmum, Capped, fixed, Flat, SequenceLimit, Rate, ActiveFrom, ActiveTo, ID)
            Using lCon As SqlConnection = Database.DBConnection
                Dim lSqlText As String = "update billing_bands set active_to = getdate() where id = @id"
                Dim lSqlCmd As New SqlCommand(lSqlText, lCon)
                With lSqlCmd.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@id", ID)
                End With
                lSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add into the GridView the onRowDeleting param which has to set the default values for the variables used for the delete.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewBands" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="BandsDataSource" OnRowDeleting="test" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="1375px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>

Protected Sub test(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim thisID As Integer = e.Values(13)
    BandsDataSource.DeleteParameters("ID").DefaultValue = thisID
    BandsDataSource.Delete()
    BandsDataSource.DataBind()
    BandsDataSource.Dispose()
End Sub
```